# Why does reflecting the name (or package path) of the error type cause a panic in Go?

Tags: go, go-reflect

Using reflection to get the name or package path of the `error` type in Golang causes the program to panic (with `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`).

What is the reasoning for this behaviour? (Doing the same operation for other built in types returns the type name and an empty string for the package path.)

I'm interested in terms of the design of the language - I can't figure out why it's desirable for this to behave differently for `error` types over other built in types.

E.g:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var str string
    strType := reflect.TypeOf(str)
    fmt.Println(strType.Name()) // OK
    fmt.Println(strType.PkgPath())  // OK

    var err error
    errType := reflect.TypeOf(err)
    fmt.Println(errType.Name()) // panics
    fmt.Println(errType.PkgPath())  // also panics
}
```

Go playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/JBMhMkjGPEV

Comment: I'm not a Go expert, so I don't know if this is relevant, but in [the source code for package builtin](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/builtin/builtin.go), `error` is the only typed defined there as an *interface.*

Comment: And if Go works like other object-oriented languages, `var err error` merely declares a *container* for an error `interface` and not an actual instantiated object.  So `errType := reflect.TypeOf(err)` returns `null`, which sounds right to me.

Comment: Your `err` is nil, your `str` isn't.

Comment: `err` is an interface, and it is nil when you declare it and not initialize. Because of that, `reflect.TypeOf(err)` is nil, and when you get the name of that, it panics.

Comment: The code in the question gets the `reflect.Type` of  the value of `err`.  The value is nil and has no type, hence the panic.  Use `reflect.TypeOf(&err).Elem()` to get the `reflect.Type` for the variable `err`.  Note the distinction between the type of the *variable* and the type of the *value*.    Try this: https://play.golang.org/p/pFtNBXEyz8w

Comment: @CeriseLimón: What is located at `&err` if the variable is never initialized?

Comment: The variable `err` is initialized to its zero value.  The  expression `&err` evaluates to the address of the variable.

Comment: `err` is an interface, not an `int`.  I'm not convinced.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All types have a [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) including interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error` is not special, except that it's an interface.

`reflect.TypeOf` takes a single argument of type `interface{}`. If you call it with a non-interface value, the value and its type is wrapped in an `interface{}`. If you call it with an interface value, the underlying value and type is extracted from the interface, and wrapped in a new `interface{}` value. If you call it with an empty interface (like you're doing here, since `error` is an interface and it's zero-initialized), then there's no underlying value and type, and the argument to `reflect.TypeOf` is a new nil `interface{}` value. `reflect.TypeOf` is defined to return `nil` in this case, leading to your nil problems.

I think your confusion is that the `TypeOf` of an interface value is the type of its underlying value, which is never an interface. You would like `TypeOf` of an interface value to be the interface type itself, but that's not how it works.